# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 while loading data from CSV to Table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, zend-framework2

I am trying to load data from `CSV` file to a table in `PHP` and `Zend`. The code is as mentioned below.

```
              $strFilePath = '"/Users/somepath/bccsv.csv"';
              $enclosed = "'\"'";
              $fieldTerminated = "','";
              $lineTerminated = "'\r\n'";
              $stmt = $this->_db->query('LOAD DATA INFILE strFilePath '. $strFilePath .' INTO TABLE partner_import_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '. $fieldTerminated . ' ENCLOSED BY '. $enclosed . ' LINES TERMINATED BY ' . $lineTerminated . ' IGNORE 1 ROWS;');
```

On executing, i am getting the error `Syntax error or access violation: 1064.`

However on executing in `mysql`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/Users/somepath/bccsv.csv"
INTO TABLE partner_import_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

It executes without error. `What is to be fixed and What is the right way to accomplish this?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating your query like you're doing it's much beter to use parameter placeholders.

```
$this->_db->query('LOAD DATA INFILE strFilePath '. $strFilePath .' INTO TABLE partner_import_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '. $fieldTerminated . ' ENCLOSED BY '. $enclosed . ' LINES TERMINATED BY ' . $lineTerminated . ' IGNORE 1 ROWS;');
```

Should be something like:

```
$this->_db->query('LOAD DATA INFILE strFilePath ? INTO TABLE partner_import_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ? ENCLOSED BY ? LINES TERMINATED BY ? IGNORE 1 ROWS;', array('/Users/somepath/bccsv.csv', ',', '"', '\r\n'));
```